# JSON Array With GSON Throws Error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to convert a JSON array to a Java object, but I am having problems understanding how to use GSON.

The JSON array looks like this:

```
"[
  {
    "category": "1",
    "checks": [
      {
        "check": "1.1",
        "penaltypoints": "1.1",
        "keypoint": "1.1"
      },
      {
        "check": "1.2",
        "penaltypoints": "1.2",
        "keypoint": "1.2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "2",
    "checks": [
      {
        "check": "2.1",
        "penaltypoints": "2.1",
        "keypoint": "2.1"
      },
      {
        "check": "2.2",
        "penaltypoints": "2.2",
        "keypoint": "2.2"
      }
    ]
  }
]"
```

My corresponding Java classes are:

```
class Category {
    public String description;
    public List<Check> checks;
}

class Check {
    public String description;
    public float penaltyPoints;
    public KeyPoint keypoint;
}

class KeyPoint {
    public String description;
}
```

And this is how I called GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();         
Category categoriesArray[] = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Category[].class);
```

At the moment it is throwing up the following error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 125
```

I am new to GSON and am having problems understanding how it works. Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting this

```
    "keypoint": "2.1"
```

to be mapped to

```
public KeyPoint keypoint;
...
class KeyPoint {
    public String description;
}
```

In Java-JSON conversions, a POJO is meant to map to a JSON object and vice versa. Here, you're trying to map a JSON **String** to a POJO. That won't work by by default.

Either write and register your own `TypeAdapter` with Gson that will do this conversion or change your JSON to

```
"keypoint" : {
     "description" : "2.1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was the problem. I had it mapped differently in my mind! I will accept your answer when the timer lets me :).